# Select particular portion of an object

Tags: python, vertices

Can anyone help me to do python scripting to extract only the vertices of particular portion of an object?
For example, if its a plane mesh I need to extract the vertices of leftmost portion of the mesh using python.

Comment: if your object is either well aligned in the world you can filter the vertices by global axis values, or you could filter by local vertex coordinated in relation to you origin.

Comment: thanks for the replay, will check it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code uses local vertex coordinates: 
For global coordinates you just multiply with "matrix_world"
Take a look also at the MeshVertex struct here:
https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.MeshVertex.html

```
import bpy

mesh = bpy.context.object.data

bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='DESELECT') 
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')

for v in mesh.vertices:
    #the location of a vertex is in MeshVertex.co as a Vector3
    #Therefore you can filter by comparing via index
    #here the z-Axis is beeing measured
    if v.co[2] > 0:  
        print(f"v is selected: {v.co}")
        v.select = True
```

Comment: Thanks it worked

Comment: @mastodonz If this answer answers your question, please consider accepting the answer by clicking on the tick icon.